# Need help in hibernate search with wild card combination lucene query

Tags: spring, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I want search my application on either on customer name and/or work order number. How can I achieve this?

```
    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Estimate.class).get();
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.bool()
                                                                    .must(queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("order.customer.customerName").matching(orderSearch.getCustomerName()+"*").createQuery())
                                                                    .must(queryBuilder.keyword().wildcard().onField("number").matching(orderSearch.getOrderNo()+"*").createQuery())
                                                                    .createQuery();
        // wrap Lucene query in a javax.persistence.Query
        org.hibernate.Query fullTextQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, Estimate.class);

        listGenericOrder = new ArrayList<GenericOrder>(fullTextQuery.list());
```

It is not working. User may input either of customer name or order number or both. Below is the link to my application on my test server.
http://dmtech.sytes.net:6080/autorepair/common/Index.html

You may visit work order module using above link. if you search using customer name as "darshan" or "test" it brings all data. This should not happen. 
In database WO12, WO13 etc work order no. is present. Searching by work order no. only doesn't bring data. 
Even if you write both "darshan" in customer name and "WO12" in work order no. textboxes, doesn't bring data though data is present in database.
Please note that getCustomerName() and getOrderNo() method give you data perfectly whatevern is typed in customer name and work order  no. textboxes respectively.
Please pardon me for my mistakes in asking a question.

Comment: What does `orderSearch.getCustomerName()` return if only the order number is specified (or vice versa)?

Comment: i have updated my question. As getCustomerName() corresponds to customer Name textbox and getOrderNo() corresponds to work Order no., providing only order no. will make getCustomerName() to return blank value.